# Spring Data JPA, dynamic sorting based upon possible entry in nested collection

Tags: spring, sorting, spring-data-jpa

As the codebase is already using Spring Data JPA, I would like to create a Sort
object, which will be based upon the presence (or lack thereof) of a particular element 
being present in a Collection, collection itself which is one of the element in the 
primary table.  The Sort object's property would need to be dynamic, as a user might want to sort
records once one way and the next time another way.

Explicitly, if multiple PrimaryEntity objects have a SecondaryEntity with 'type' set to a particular
value, I would then want to sort them based upon the corresponding 'notes' field in the corresponding
SecondaryEntity.  Also, while I would want to retrieve all SecondaryEntity objects, I would want the 
sorting to be based solely upon the SecondaryEntity records where 'type' is equal to, say, 'Important'.

The classes look like the following (I also redefined 'equals' & 'hashCode' for SecondaryEntity):

```
public class PrimaryEntity 
{

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "primary", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapKey(name = "type")
private Map<String, SecondaryEntity> myMap = new HashMap<>();

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

}

public class SecondaryEntity 
{

@Column(name = "type", length = 200)
private String type;

@Column(name = "notes", length = 2000)
private String notes;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "primary_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private PrimaryEntity primary;

 }
```

I would then want to create a Sort with a syntax similar to he following:

Sort sort = new Sort("myMap[important].notes")

Finally, while I am striving to sort the PrimaryEntity records as per above, it does not matter to 
me how, for a given PrimaryEntity, its SecondaryEntity records are displayed.

For example,

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Notes</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second primary</td>
    <td>Important</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second primary</td>
    <td>Other</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second primary</td>
    <td>Miscellaneous</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Third primary</td>
    <td>Important</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First primary</td>
    <td>Important</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at custom repositories?

Comment: Hello, if the answer helped you don't forget to accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You can optionally override `findAll(Sort sort)` method in the `SecondaryRepo` with `@EntityGraph` annotation:

```
public interface SecondaryRepo extends JpaRepository<Secondary, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"primary"})
    @Override
    List<Secondary> findAll(Sort sort);
}
```

to fetch associated Primaries eagerly.

Then just define `Sort` with `type` and `note` and fetch Secondaries (that will contain also their Primaries) like this:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(new Sort.Order("type"), new Sort.Order("note"));
List<Secondary> list = secondaryRepo.findAll(sort);
```

See [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example11) and [test](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/blob/master/src/test/java/restsdemo/example11/SortTest.java).